# Why is my index variable not iterating my list correctly?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I wrote a small piece of code to iterate over a list and sum the contents (I know there is a built in function but wanted to do this out of curiosity).

```
list = [14, 42, 100, 15, 8, 16, 104, 8, 41, 5, 15, 10]    
index = 1
result = list[0]
for range in (0, len(list)):
    result = result + list[index]
    index = index + 1
print(result)
```

For some reason the index variable iterates until '3' and just stops. Thanks for the help.

Comment: why don't you use `sum(list)`

Comment: please don't use `list`, and `range` for variable names since they're builtin to Python.

Comment: The code runs but stops at index 3 and gives the result of 156. As I said before this more out of curiosity/learning than anything because I know we can use len(list)

Answer (score 3):

**Why?**

Because `for range in (0, len(list))` will iterate *only* two times:

1. With value 0.
2. With value `len(list)` which is 12.

So, you end up adding only first 3 elements in list.

```
# Wrong code
result = list[0]
for range in (0, len(list)):
    result = result + list[index]
    index = index + 1

# 14 + 42 + 100 = 156
```

**Corrected**:

```
lst = [14, 42, 100, 15, 8, 16, 104, 8, 41, 5, 15, 10]

result = 0    
for i in range(len(lst)):
    result = result + lst[i]

print(result)
```

More **pythonically**:

```
lst = [14, 42, 100, 15, 8, 16, 104, 8, 41, 5, 15, 10]

result = 0    
for x in lst:
    result += x

print(result)
```

**Shorter**:

```
sum(lst)
```

---

**Note**-

Don't name:

- your list as `list` as it shadows the built-in [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).
- your variable as `range` as it shadows the built-in [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: Thank you. One thing that confuses me is why you say it iterates twice. If it iterates once with a value of zero, ok, but then how does it iterate once with a value of 12?

Comment: `range` takes value 0 in one iteration, 12 in the other. There are no more elements in the tuple, so it stops after two iterations.

Comment: @Hydra17 you can try `for i in (0,12): print(i)` it loops through tuple not range. `range` is builtin so it's good practice to **not** to use them as variable name.

Comment: Also, don't use `range` as a variable name

Answer (score 1):

this is really basic.

```
summ = 0
for i in range(len(list)):
    summ += list[i]
```

your for-loop is simply incorrect. You iterate over the elements of the tuple with two elements, plus one sums up to three...

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a tuple with two elements, `0` and `len(list)`.
You should use range, to get a range over all numbers from 0 to `len(list)`:

```
result = list[0]
for index in range(1, len(list)):
    result = result + list[index]
```

but you should iterate over the elements of the list directly:

```
numbers = [14, 42, 100, 15, 8, 16, 104, 8, 41, 5, 15, 10]    
result = 0
for number in numbers:
    result += number
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution: when you want to get each element’s index and value at the same time, a more elegant solution uses enumerate(). This avoids us to worry about len and incrementing the index

**Note:**  We are not using the index below though

```
lst = [14, 42, 100, 15, 8, 16, 104, 8, 41, 5, 15, 10]

result = 0    
for i, num in enumerate(lst):
    result += num

print(result)
```

Comment: If we don't need index, we don't need `enumerate` also when it can be iterated just with a `for` loop.